# In MS Word, how do you create a list in table that separate bullet and content?

Tags: ms-word

So I have this table with 2 columns and I want to put a list in it such that

```
+-------------------------------+
|    *  | Content 1             |
|    *  | Content 2             |
|    *  | Content 3             |
|    *  | Content 4             |
|    *  | Content 5             |
+-------------------------------+
```

the bullet is in the left cell, and the content is on the right cell, is this possible?  I am using MS Word 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a two-column table, set column widths to automatically adjusted (or something else, as you like) and you enter the bullet character “•” in the cells of the first column, e.g. by typing Alt+0149. I don’t think there’s a way to generate the bullets automatically in the same sense as you can control the bullets in a bulleted list.